# $f$ continuous, $a_n\neq2,\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=2, b_n=\frac{f(a_n)-f(2)}{a_n-2}, b_n$ converges $\Rightarrow f$ is differentiable at $x=2$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

So I've been struggling with this prove/disprove question:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let $a_n\neq2, b_n $ be two sequences such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=2$ and $b_n=\frac{f(a_n)-f(2)}{a_n-2}.$ Prove or disprove that if $b_n$ converges, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=2$.

Since f is continuous, I realized that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n)=f(2)$, but that is essentially it. I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the "$\frac{0}{0}$" limit. It did occur to me, though, that this limit looks like a derivative, however I have no idea how to deal with it when it comes to sequences (Heine doesn't seem to help me much here).

Thank you very much and have a beautiful day.

Comment: Hint: $f$ does *not* have to be differentiable, look for a counterexample.

Comment: @Wojowu Oh well that wasn't hard. I was so concentrated on proving the statement that I forgot that it might be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Wojowu If $f$ is differentiable for every $x\neq 2$, can I say that $b_n$ is bounded?

Comment: No, it needn't be bounded. Unless you are still assuming $b_n$ is convergent, then of course it is bounded.

Comment: @Wojowu Hmm, I see. It seems that I have an example for that, but the problem is that the $f$ that I chose would be differentiable for every *real* $x$. I can't find an example where $f$ is differentiable for every real $x$ apart from $2$. Could you help me with this one too? Much appriciated.

Comment: Involving the absolute value function should help

Comment: @Wojowu I think I'm stuck. The only examples I can think of are quite problematic, mainly because the domain of $f$ would not be the whole $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false.

For example if you let $f(x) = |x - 2|$ and $a_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 2$$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(a_n) - f(2)}{a_n - 2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1 $$
So $b_n$ converges, but $f$ is not differentiable at $2$.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the counterexample I eventually used (although it was $|x-2|$ for me rather than $|x|-2$).

Comment: Oh yes, that is a typo. It should be $|x-2|$.